# Biztalk File Moving

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013

I have an xml file which consists of "File Id" attribute which denotes the file id of some pdf document.

```
<StoredDocumentRepresentation>
<DigitalFile FileId="3BSE077611_B001.pdf" xlink:href="files/3BSE077611_B001.pdf" xlink:type="SIMPLE"></DigitalFile>
</StoredDocumentRepresentation>
```

There will be many pdf with different FileId(pdf will be having FileId as their name)in the Receive Location. I need to pick the pdf with File id mentioned in the xml...
Thanks in Advance

Comment: What's your issue ? Parsing the XML ? Please be more specific.

Comment: I need to pick the pdf file based on the File Id mentioned in the xml...each pdf files are saved with some File Id and this file id will be mentioned in the xml file...

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Comment: Thanks for your interest Dijkgraaf..

Answer (score 0):

I have used the File.Move() function in my orchestration for picking the PDF files automatically from source to destination location, once my xml file is dropped...